# How can I use 2d vector as class member in private for create a game-board?

Tags: c++, vector

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class board{
        public:
        
      /*  vector<vector<int>>getmyvector(){
            return vect;
        }
        board(vector<vector<int>>vect2){
            vect=vect2;
        }*/
        
        private:
        vector<vector<int>vect;
        
    };

/* vector<vector<int>> getmyvector(){               //getter   
     return vect;
 }
 
board :: board(vector<vector<int>>vect2):vect(vect2){  //constructor     
    
}
*/


int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>>vec;
    
    vec{
    {0,0,1,1,2},
    {1,1,0,2,1},
    {1,1,2,2,0},
    };
    board a(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to creat a 2d vector in private.But ı try access this vector ı get fail.How can ı load a board 2d vector in private and how can ı use this board publically  ? How can ı create a getter,setter or constructor for 2d vector?

Comment: The function definition `getmyvector()` is not of a member function.

Comment: Maybe try to simplify. In a copy of your project, replace your `vector<vector<int>>` with `int`, and adjust your initializations to match. Does that work? (If not, you can drop all mention of vectors from your question.)

Comment: *"ı get fail."* -- this is an inadequate description of a problem. You should uncomment the part of your [mre] that causes a compilation error and paste that error message into your question. That would satisfy the requirement for debugging questions to include a *specific* error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below given program as a starting point(reference). The class `board` has a private data member named `vect` and public member functions called `getVector`, `setVector` and `display`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class board{
    public:
      //create getter 
      std::vector<std::vector<int>> getVector() const 
      {
          return vect;
      }
      
      //create setter
      void setVector(std::vector<std::vector<int>> pvect)
      {
          vect = pvect;
      }
      
      //display() function that prints elements of the vect data member
      void display()
      {
          for(const std::vector<int> &elem: vect)
          {
              for(int intElem: elem)
              {
                  std::cout<<intElem<<std::endl;
              }
          }
      }

    private:
     std::vector<std::vector<int>> vect;
    
};

int main()
{
    //create a board instance
    board myBoard;
    
   
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vect{
    {0,0,1,1,2},
    {1,1,0,2,1},
    {1,1,2,2,0},
    };
    
    //use the setter to set the vect data member
    myBoard.setVector(vect);
    
    //lets print out the elements of the data member vect for the object myBoard using the display() member function
    myBoard.display();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/vJHqfGxvk).